# SQl file and comments

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, deployment, ddl

I have a `SQl` file generated using a batch command . The batch just collates all `SQl` files under a directory to a single file for deployment. Individual pieces work fine in the deployment file but it gives an error that says `"Incorrect syntax near ''.".`

It is because of the comments section in the file, but I fail to understand what causes the error in the comments section

The code snippet is below.

```
         /*
        -----------------------------------------------------------------------
     <copyright file="tblMPI_Configuration.sql" company="">

     </copyright>
     -----------------------------------------------------------------------

     Author: 


     Modification Log:
        $Id: tblMPI_Configuration.sql 22746 2013-06-19 13:20:46Z xxxxxxx $

     Description:
        This table holds the MPI Config Information
        */
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE type = 'U' AND name = 'MPI_Configuration')
        BEGIN
            DROP  Table MPI_Configuration
        END
    GO


    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MPI_Configuration](
        [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [SourceType] [varchar](3) NULL,
        [Item] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
        [Value] [varchar](50) NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_MPI_Configuration] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [ID] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

    GO


    /*
     -----------------------------------------------------------------------
     <copyright file="tblMPI_LKUP_MatchingStatus.sql" company="">

     </copyright>
     -----------------------------------------------------------------------

     Author: 


     Modification Log:
        $Id: tblMPI_LKUP_MatchingStatus.sql 22746 2013-06-19 13:20:46Z xxxxxxx $

     Description:
        This table holds the MPI matching status
        */
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE type = 'U' AND name = 'MPI_LKUP_MatchingStatus')
        BEGIN
            DROP  Table MPI_LKUP_MatchingStatus
        END
    GO

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MPI_LKUP_MatchingStatus](
        [MPI_StatusCode] [int] NOT NULL,
        [MPI_StatusMessage] [varchar](100) NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_MPI_LKUP_MatchingStatus] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [MPI_StatusCode] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

    GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is your batch file merging these files?  There is a `<feff>` before the second comment.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark.

```
    <feff>/*  <--------------------------------------------------------- Here
     -----------------------------------------------------------------------
     <copyright file="tblMPI_LKUP_MatchingStatus.sql" company="">

     </copyright>
     -----------------------------------------------------------------------

     Author: 


     Modification Log:
        $Id: tblMPI_LKUP_MatchingStatus.sql 22746 2013-06-19 13:20:46Z xxxxxxx $

     Description:
        This table holds the MPI matching status
        */
```

And here is what Google showed me: http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/789853/sql-text-containing-a-byte-order-mark-fails-to-execute.

Also have a look at this link for possible fixes: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/01185066-a387-4c49-8087-e472182935ef/urgetnt-byte-order-mark-error-error-reading-data-from-sql-server-using-custom-pipeline